Using DotCover command line to find Code coverage of a dotnet application using Selenium
I am trying to find Code coverage of a Dotnet application using DotCover command line by selenium automation framework.
By running my application in debug mode and attaching it to DotCover UI process and running automation tests in the background, I am able to find the code coverage of the application.
Now I want to run this from command line and integrate it with CI/CD.
Can someone help me with this?
I have tried running it from command line.
dotcover.exe cover --output="path_to_report" --TargetExecutable="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --TargetArguments="path_to_dll" --WorkingDir="working_directory"'
After running this I run selenium tests. I can see the requests coming in the logs but no report being generated.
Note - Using DotCover console runner 2024.1.2. Build 20240506.152321 (windows-x64).

Try adding test to your target arguments.
dotcover.exe cover --output="path_to_report" --TargetExecutable="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --TargetArguments="test path_to_dll" --WorkingDir="working_directory"

